# Simplifying if-else-if ladder such that the function calls are made only once

Tags: c, if-statement, optimization

How would you simplify the following if-else-if ladder such that the function call is made only once?

```
if (Condition A){
    A();
}
else {
    if (Condition B) {
        A();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (A || B)` ?

Comment: @AdiC which is, of course, completely optional!

Comment: @FelixPalmen True... But that's why I put '***please***', as it's optional

Comment: Well, some suggest waiting a bit with accepting the very first answer to encourage some additional answers..

Comment: In fact, I greatly encourage questioners not to mark any answer correct for at least 24 hours--it should be a rule. Very often, an early answer might work in some limited way, and then a much better, more complete answer will come along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
if ((Condition A) || (Condition B)) {
    A();
}
```

As you want the function `A()` to run if `Condition A` is `true` or if `Condition B` is `true`, you can use the `||` (OR) operator. This returns `true` if either conditions are `true`.

Comment: This will even work if `A` or `B` are having side effects.

Comment: because of shortcut effect :)

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I afraid not. The version before edit wont compile, version after the edit invalidates your comment

Comment: I am assuming it is a pseudo-code. Also not sure why the edit is invalidating it.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. and you wrote something about side effects? It stops to be a pseudo code then. https://ideone.com/cCO9MM `if (Condition A) || (Condition B) {` this syntax is illegal in C

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I don't see it on my level of pedantism.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in general you cant simplify this "tree" of ifs.  If he second (or next) condition has a side effect. So it always good to consider why someone has done it this way.

Examples:

```
if(readbytefromUART() == 'b' || readbytefromUART() == 'c') .......
/* if condition ... == 'b' is met , there is no second call to the function
```

or more common mistake in the code

```
if(readbytefromUART() == 'b' && readbytefromUART() == 'c') .......
/* if condition ... == 'b' is not met , there is no second call to the function
```

https://ideone.com/cCO9MM

syntax proposed in the another answer

```
if (cond1) || (cond2) {
```

is illegal in C and it wont compile

Comment: The parentheses are simply in the wrong place in the last example.

Comment: No, but it makes it uninteresting.  Also, it should have been a comment on that answer, and there’s no such code in the (one) other answer now.